# Django: Update or Change previous saved model data

Tags: python, django, database, model, updates

I have this code in my forms.py

```
    ref_user = User.objects.get(
    username=form.cleaned_data['referrer']
    )

    user = User.objects.create_user(
    username=form.cleaned_data['username']
    )

    # Count the referrer's direct referrals
    ref_recruits = DirectReferral.objects.filter(referrer=ref_user).count()

    # Get newly created direct referral
    get_ref = DirectReferral.objects.get(name=user)

    #Check if ref_recruits is not divisible by 2 or paired
    if ref_recruits % 2 != 0:

        # Newly created direct referral is_paired is False
        get_ref.is_paired = False
        get_ref.save()

    else:

        # Newly created direct referral is_paired is True
        get_ref.is_paired = True
        get_ref.save()

        # But I also want to update the previous is_paired to True 
        # of the same referrer
```

> How do I update the previous is_paired to True of the same referrer?

Check image below to have a better understanding of what I mean.
[image]
I hope you understand.

models.py(requested)

```
class DirectReferral(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, primary_key=True)
    referrer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="direct_referrals")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    is_paired = models.NullBooleanField(null=False)
```

Comment: Could you please show DirectReferral model code?

Comment: @Paul I added models.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should refactor your code. As per your implementation, I believe `name` field for `DirectReferral' will be unique.

```
ref_user = User.objects.get(
username=form.cleaned_data['referrer']
)

user = User.objects.create_user(
username=form.cleaned_data['username']
)

# Count the referrer's direct referrals
ref_recruits = DirectReferral.objects.filter(referrer=ref_user).count()

# Get newly created direct referral
get_ref = DirectReferral.objects.get(name=user)

#Check if ref_recruits is not divisible by 2 or paired
if ref_recruits % 2 == 0:
    get_ref.is_paired = True
    DirectReferral.objects.filter(referrer=ref_user, is_paired=False).update(is_paired=True)
else:
    get_ref.is_paired = False
get_ref.save()
```

Comment: Yes, every refererrer has only one unique DirectReferral.

Answer (score 0):

You need to order your `DirectReferral` objects somehow so they are returned in correct order, i.e. the last added one is the first one in a `DirectReferral` objects list, then you can easily change the second object in a list, which is in your situation a previous one.

For example:

```
get_refs = DirectReferral.objects.filter(referrer=ref_user).ordery_by('-timestamp')

if ref_recruits % 2 != 0:
    get_refs[0].is_paired = False
    get_refs[0].save()

else:
    get_refs[0].is_paired = True
    get_refs[1].is_paired = True
    get_refs[0].save()
    get_refs[1].save()
```

Comment: I tried this but I don't why is_paired is not saved or updated. It only returns a question mark in my model data.